# Unix to Dos Conversion in C#

Tags: c#

One of my senior created exe for unix to dos conversion.

- what basic difference between them?

I have a .tex file . and I run that exe with file(as a parameter passing).

Then i check with original .tex file.

No differences after executing the unixtodos.exe

Both are same.

- Could anyone help me to analyse the file with unixtodos.exe?

Comment: I think it'll be a great idea if you done your own homework. That way you'll learn a thing or two

Comment: The difference between UNIX and DOS/Windows is the line ending character. In UNIX it is a single line feed (ASCII 10) while in Windows it is carriage return followed by line feed (ASCII 13 10).

Comment: http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/Courses/Common/dosvunix.html or 
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-dos-and-unix/ or even
http://ibiblio.org/team/intro/unix/dos.html 
start with theese and come back if you need more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you check the file size for comparison of old and new?
As the line endings differs from platform to platform (Unix: "\n", Windows: "\r\n"), the file size should differ after conversion.

A normal text editor don't show you the difference. Some text editors like notepad++ are showing the line ending used in the lower right corner of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n"). You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are translated properly.

A regular text editor won't show you any differences between the original and converted file.